# Is my .htaccess code wrong?

Tags: .htaccess, cache-control

Cache checking sites like Google PageSpeed keep showing my files cached for only 2 hours. Is there something wrong with my htaccess file? Order of the rules? Thanks

-All other rules in the file work.
(Well I did have some code to turn off ETags which didn't seem to work either)

-I'm using CloudFlare but support tells me there is nothing in cloudflare affecting the cache times.

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

################ Require ending trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>


## ENABLE COMPRESSION ##
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 410 /410.php
```

I then have several RewriteCond's

Comment: Do you have mod_expires enabled? The `<IfModule>` would be skipped if not. Comment out the surrounding `<IfModule></IfModule>` lines to force all the `Expires` to run - does it blow up with a 500 error?

Comment: I would advise you to edit your post to remove your domain from the rewrite rules too - if you leave it as is, this may be misconstrued as a spam post.

Comment: I removed the <IfModule mod_expires.c> and </IfModule> and there was no change.
I also replaced the domain, I had left it there in case someone wanted to run a test.

Comment: I assume you must have fixed this? I've just run a page through Google's PageSpeed Insights and it's OK. (?) The only 2 files that are prompted with regards to caching are external to your site. _Aside:_ "`RewriteOptions inherit`" - This suggests you have other mod_rewrite directives in parent directories/server config that are required. Otherwise, this should be removed. Your canonical redirect doesn't redirect HTTP www to HTTPS, however, your site does appear to perform this redirect, so I guess you must have code elsewhere (in the server config?) that does this?

Comment: No it is not fixed perhaps you were looking at the wrong site. 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.321sexchat.com%2F Its showing me 17 local files that are cached for 2 hours

I have CloudFlare redirecting http to https
and I have several RewriteCond below the code snippet provided.

Does the fact that these files are set to 2 hours mean that the server or cloudflare are giving caching instructions somewhere or is 2 hours a common default?

Comment: @w3dk Any other thoughts?

Comment: I got the URL from the edit history (and it's the same as the link you've provided) - that link gives good results for me? 96/100 on Desktop and 90/100 on Mobile - there are no local files cached for 2 hours. This would seem to be something to do with your locale?? I thought CloudFlare had it's own cache settings? If I check the HTTP response headers of some images etc. they all look OK as well. What `RewriteCond` directives do you have? (Although it's `RewriteRule` that's the important one, `RewriteCond` directives are meaningless by themselves.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mod_expires override setup for the vhost in the apache config file.